# Dynamically creating cases for a php switch statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a switch statement in php which will determine what a mysql query will be based on posted data.  The amount data that is posted varies based on the database, which creates the form.  Is there any way that I can have the possible cases pull from the database because the same code is executed for all of them with some case specific modifications. The reason I don't just use one possibility instead of the switch is because there are other non database related cases that can feed into the switch.

This may clear things up

I have 2 pages people.php and edit.php.  people.php dynamically creates a table of members in a building based on the building Id which is sent via get.  From this table a user can select what they would like to change about the records from a drop down menu and then the script posts everything to edit.php.  If a user wishes to change someone's building then the switch case catches thais and creates a form to ask which building they will be changed to. This then posts back to edit.php.  Do I have to hard code each building into the switch or can I make it dynamically create cases based on the available buildings from mysql?

`echo"<td><select name='action'>
        <option value='save' selected='yes'>Save Changes</option>
        <option value='delete'>Delete Record</option>
        <option value='more'>Add Additional Phone Numbers and or Email Addresses</option>
        <option value='building'>Change This person's Building</option>
        </select></td>"`

this is created in every row of the table of people which will determine what the form will do with the data in edit.php

```
switch ($_POST['action'])
{
        case 'save':
                update($_POST);
                header("Location: people.php?bid=".$_POST['bid']);
                break;
        case 'delete': //Havent written delete person code yet
                break;
        case 'more': //havent written add more phone number or emails yet
                break;
        case 'building': echo "Move ".$_POST['fname']." ".$_POST['mname']." ".$_POST['lname']." to which building?
                <br/><form action='edit.php' method='POST'><select name='action'>"
                compile_permissions($_SESSION['uid']);
                foreach($_SESSION['buildings'] as $value)
                {
                        $query="select name from schools where bid='$value'";
                        $result=mysql_query($query);
                        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                        echo "<option value='$value'> Move to ".$row['name']."</option>";
                }
                echo "</select><br/><input type='submit' value='Go'></form>"
                break;
        default: header("Location:index.php");
                break;
}
```

I Need to pass the pid and the bid to edit.php with this form so I can use a query to update their building how can I go about doing this?

Comment: Without seeing code, it's really hard to give you any helpful feedback. We can make all kinds of assumptions, but we'd be shooting in the dark.

Comment: One thing is certain: PHP doesn't really support the kind of meta-programming necessary to "dynamically create `switch` cases". But that's not really necessary either, you'll probably just need to use a loop to go through your cases pulled from the database instead.

Comment: You are over complicating things. You need to separate your code more. Break it down further into smaller classes. You are creating a maintenance night mare.

Comment: @sims thanks I was trying to condense to save code, but I see how it will make it much more complicated.

Comment: @Bmore, Sometimes you want a really lean piece of code. But what you are making looks complex enough to warrant several classes. You could even write simple router that will act on the request based on certain values, for example your $_POST['action']. That router can load other classes and call methods, etc. I would also try to keep the HTML output separate. That's going into MVC. I'm not sure how big this is. You could use a small framework like Codeigniter to lay the ground work.

Comment: Ever heard about [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)?

Answer (score 0):

It does sounds like you need to split up your code into more parts, but if you're looking for building dynamic code, check out eval().  You can build into a string and then use that to execute it.  Not sure if that will help you or not at this point.